# Sweaters of the same material with different ironing indication

Tags: clothing, temperature, fabric

I have 2 sweaters from different brands. Both are of the same material: 100% merino wool.
There is a difference is the heaviness (if I am using the right term). One feels a bit thicker/more tightly woven than the other.
Question: Their labels show different indication on ironing. One shows the iron icon with 1 circle and the other sweater's label shows the iron icon with 2 circles.
How is it possible for 2 sweaters of the same material the ironing instruction to be different?

Answer (score 3):

Clothing manufacturers often put in cleaning and ironing instructions which are way to careful for the fabrics so people will not return the item when it has gone wrong in the wash.

I own white 100 % cotton T-shirts with a 'no hot wash, no ironing' instruction, which I ignore and they do not come to harm.

I expect both your sweaters should come out well after ironing on the lower setting and should not be damaged when ironing carefully on the higher setting.
But when dried laying flat or carefully hung on a clothes hook so it is in the proper shape it likely needs no ironing.

Comment: Are the icons on the labels under one standard? I.e. can it be that an iron icon with 1 bullet in one chart be the same as an iron icon with 2 bullets in another or something like that?

Comment: They should indicate the same temperature settings as that is also what is used for the people making the irons, which is a world wide market.